# Typescript variable existence check

Tags: typescript

Consider the following code:

```
let str: string | null;

function print(msg: string) {
    console.log(msg);
}


print(str);
```

in this case typescript compiler give me an error, saying correctly that *Argument of type 'string | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.*

This could simply fixed checking for *str* existence, so

```
let str: string | null;

function print(msg: string) {
    console.log(msg);
}

if (str) {
    print(str);
}
```

compile without errors. Typescript compiler i smart enough to understand the check.

Now suppose you check variable existence within a method, for example

```
let str: string | null;

function print(msg: string) {
    console.log(msg);
}

function check(str: string) {
    return str != null;
}

if (check(str)) {
    print(str);
}
```

In this case typescrip do not understand that the call to *print* method is safe.
How can I fix this?

---

EDIT

To be clear, this is (more or less) the skelethon of my class:

ok, but my case is a little bit more complex.
This is, more or less the structure of my class:

```
class Clazz {
    private myProp: {
        aString?: string
        anotherString?: number
    };

    constructor(aParam: any) {
        this.myProp = {};
        if (aParam.aString) {
            this.myProp.aString = aParam.aString;
        }

        if (aParam.anotherString) {
            this.myProp.anotherString = aParam.anotherString;
        }
    }

    public haveAString() {
        return this.myProp.aString != null;
    }

    public haveAnotherString() {
        return this.myProp.anotherString != null;
    }

    public computation1() {
        if (this.haveAString()) {
            this.doAComputation(this.myProp.aString);
        }
    }

    public computation2() {
        if (this.haveAnotherString()) {
            this.doAComputation(this.myProp.anotherString);
        }
    }

    private doAComputation(str: string) {
        // do something with the string
    }

}
```

How should I fix in my case?

Answer (score 2):

The compiler will not follow checks across function boundaries, but you can use a custom type guard to achieve the same effect

```
let str: string | null;

function print(msg: string) {
    console.log(msg);
}

function check(str: string| null) : str is string{
    return str != null;
}

if (check(str)) {
    print(str);
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  Now, my case is a little different, my *check* method do not accept params. I've edited my question..

Comment: @Canemacchina type guards and private members don't play well.. Maybe we could get something to work for a public member but for privates I don't think there is any hope.. Still thinking about it though, maybe someone else has an idea...

Comment: I'll end up with good tests and manually instructing the compiler that `aString` is not null or undef